# Choosing the weights of a Voronoi diagram -- is this function always the gradient of another function?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convexity, computational-geometry

This question is related to the earlier question  [Weighted area of a Voronoi cell](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78103/weighted-area-of-a-voronoi-cell) .  As in that question, let $X = \{ x_1,\dots,x_n\} $ denote a set of $n$ points in the unit square $S = [0,1]\times[0,1]$, and let $w = \{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ denote a set of weights corresponding to the $n$ points in $X$.  Define the "power diagram" of $X$ in $S$ to be a partition of $S$ into at most $n$ pieces $V_i(\mathbf{w})$, where

$V_i(\mathbf{w}) = \{x\in S: \|x - x_i\|^2 + w_i \leq \|x - x_j\|^2 + w_j \forall j \neq i \}$

i.e. a "weighted Voronoi diagram".  Thus, larger values of $w_i$ correspond to smaller cells $V_i$.  The cells are always convex, and the partition does not change if we add a constant to all terms of a weight vector $\mathbf{w}$.

My question is:  let's consider some quantity $Q(V_i(\mathbf{w}))$ associated with the Voronoi cells with the following monotonicity property:  for any two weight vectors $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{w}'$, if it turns out that $V_i(\mathbf{w})\subsetneq V_i(\mathbf{w}')$, then $Q(V_i(\mathbf{w})) < Q(V_i(\mathbf{w}'))$.  Examples of $Q$ would be the area, perimeter, diameter, or width of the cells.  I want to know:  is it always the case that $Q(V_i(\mathbf{w}))$ is somehow "equivalent" to the gradient of some other function?

My reasoning for this question is as follows:  let's say we want to select weights $\mathbf{w}$ such that $Q(V_i(\mathbf{w}))$ is equal for all $i$.  This means that we want to *increase*(resp. decrease) values of $w_i$ for those regions where $Q(V_i(\mathbf{w}))$ is large (resp. small).  A sensible way to do this would be to iteratively set $w_i \mapsto w_i + \epsilon Q(V_i(\mathbf{w})) $, where $\epsilon$ is some tiny stepsize.  I have tried numerical experiments with this scheme for the case where $Q$ measures area or perimeter and this seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the last paragraph of your question, it might seem reasonable to reformulate the question as: can we always select weights $\mathbf{w}$, such that the values $Q(V_i(\mathbf{w}))$ satisfy prescribed ratios: if we normalize by the sum of all entries $$s(\mathbf{w}):=\sum_{i=1}^nQ(V_i(\mathbf{w}))$$
we get a vector
 $$Q_{\text{norm}}(\mathbf{w}):=\frac{1}{s(\mathbf{w})}(Q(V_i(\mathbf{w})))_{1\leq i\leq n}$$
which is contained in the simplex $\Delta_{n-1}=\{(x_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}|\sum_i=1\}$. Then the question is: can we find for every point $p\in\Delta_{n-1}$ weights $\mathbf{w}$ such that $Q_{\text{norm}}=p$.
For example if we take $p$ to be the barycenter of $\Delta_{n-1}$, then we would want to select weights such that $Q(V_i(\mathbf{w}))$ are equal for all $i$.

I can answer this question completely under the additional assumption that $Q$ is continuous. (Your examples "area, perimeter, diameter, or width of the cells" are all continous). What we need to prove is the surjectivity of the continous map $$Q_{\text{norm}}\colon\, \mathbb{R}^n\to \Delta_{n-1}.$$
We consider a map $$\begin{align}f\colon\, \Delta_{n-1}&\to\mathbb{R}^n\\x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)&\mapsto f(x)=(\log(x_1),\dots,\log(x_n)).\end{align}$$
This is only defined on the interior of $\Delta_{n-1}$, but we extend the definition on the boundary $\partial\Delta_{n-1}$ by setting $\log(0)=-\infty$. Also we extend the definition of the Voronoi diagram to allow some (but not all) components of the weight vector to be $-\infty$; the coresponding Voronoi regions will be empty. These definitions then allow us to compose $f$ with $Q_{\text{norm}}$ to get the map $$Q_{\text{norm}}\circ f\colon\, \Delta_{n-1}\to\Delta_{n-1},$$
which is continous and has the nice properties to map faces to faces: If some coordinates of $x$ are zero, the corresponding coordinates in $f(x)$ are $-\infty$ and the corresponding coordinates in $Q_{\text{norm}}\circ f(x)$ are also zero, since the corresponding Voronoi regions are empty.
Therefore a face of $\Delta_{n−1}$ is mapped to itself.

Then we can apply a little (but often useful) lemma from algebraic topology that just states that such a map must be surjective. See for this question (an the answers): [Map from simplex to itself that preserves sub-simplices](https://mathoverflow.net/q/67318/39495). Hence $Q_{\text{norm}}\circ f$ is surjective and therefore also $Q_{\text{norm}}$ is surjective, which is what we wanted to show.

**Edit**: If $Q$ is taken to be the area and you are looking for an all equal area partition, then this partition is even *unique* up to sets of measure zero. A nice proof of this geometrical proof is given in the following paper, where they also consider some generalizations of the question:

> [Darius Geiß, Rolf Klein, Rainer Penninger, and Günter Rote, *Optimally solving a transportation problem using Voronoi diagrams*,  Computational Geometry, Theory and Applications 46 (2013), 1009–1016, special issue for the 28th European Workshop on Computational Geometry (EuroCG'12).](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rote/Papers/abstract/Optimally+solving+a+transportation+problem+using+Voronoi+diagrams.html)

(It is not the *first* proof of this results, see the references of this paper.)

Comment: Hey thanks!  That argument is very helpful.  I'll be curious to see if I can apply this kind of reasoning to show that the map $w_i \mapsto w_i + \epsilon Q(V_i(\mathbf{w}))$ converges.

Comment: @TomSolberg I find it quite plausible that this should converge.